# Js write function that split string by camelCase dont work

Tags: javascript

I want to create simple function that split string by camelCase.
The problem when i write the code as a function and try to use this, it doesnt working.

```
var a = cutCamelCase('whereName');
console.log(a); // thats undefined

function cutCamelCase(str) {
  str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
  });
}

var b = 'whereName'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(b); //thats ["where", "name"]
```

plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/69vGg070T8J0mewr5fo8?p=preview

Comment: What part about it isn't working, exactly?

Comment: console.log(a) is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead - you aren't returning a result in your method.

```
function cutCamelCase(str) {
  return str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a return statement before str.split to get the same result

```
return str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cutCamelCase(str) {
    return str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function (s) {
        return s.toLowerCase();
    });
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

your are not storing result of split function and function returned null and exit try following code

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmgzk7ak/)

```
function cutCamelCase(str)
 {  
     var result = str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(s) {
         return s.toLowerCase();
     });
 return result;
 }
```

Comment: interesting, this is the exact same answer as the other ones.

Comment: @JayHarris i was working on jsfiddle when other post answer before me

Comment: well you just wasted a jsfiddle link. lol your about 11 mins off here, 'you gotta be quicker than that'.